# nginx only downloads a file on a virtual host

Tags: nginx, mac-osx

*I am trying to port my local environment on a mac to use nginx*

from the logs I first got `[emerg] 9449#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)`
but running `sudo nginx` solved this

now if I input the address `http://njsphp.dev`, it just downloads a file?

in the conf I have set a virtual host and I have put the name in the **hosts** file

```
server{
    listen       80;
    listen     njsphp.dev;

    server_name njsphp.dev;
    root /Users/redres/Webdev/nodejsphp;
    index index.phtml index.htm;
         location / {
        }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only root is allowed to bind ports <1024. Check that you run nginx as regular user or www-data user or root. Nginx has drop privilages mechanism to do it. You run it as root, nginx binds to 80 then drop privilages to user pointed in configuration.

UPDATE:

Of course giving root/admin privilages is only one method. You can use `selinux` or [`CAP_NET_ADMIN` linux capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) to give access only to binding port below 1024 and nothing else.

Comment: @spinus, could you explain this in more detail please? I don't quite understand and could use this solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @AndyJones there is nothing to explain. Only privileges (root/administrator or application with privileges to do that) can use ports below 1024. So you have to use ports above 1024 or grant privileges to application.

Comment: Keep in mind that neither SELinux nor Linux capabilities are available on this user's Mac.